# Smart banner is not working on iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, smartbanner

In iOS7 safari, clicking smart banner "open" button doesn't trigger UIApplication::openURL:(NSURL *)....

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

This issue reproduced only in iOS7. I have a feeling that this is a bug in iOS7.

Comment: Same happened to me, while iOS6 devices are working completely fine, iOS7 devices are just ignoring the `app-argument` parameter.

Comment: Have you filed a Radar?

Comment: I filed Apple bug report #15238526. Never heard of Radar before. +1 for suggesting.

Comment: Official reply from Apple as follow "Engineering has determined that your bug report (15238526) is a duplicate of another issue (14712951) and will be closed.

Comment: A note to everyone experiencing this who hasn't filed a Radar yet -- DO IT YOURSELF even though Hussain got a duplicate, as you will. The number of duplicates of a Radar bug is directly and strongly correlated to how important addressing it becomes internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well-known bug in iOS 7.

http://openradar.appspot.com/15229369

http://openradar.appspot.com/14712951

https://devforums.apple.com/message/897373#897373

Get all your developer buddies to keep filing duplicate Radars until Apple deigns to address the issue is your only option here.

Comment: Did my part.  Filed 15488187.  Still not fixed in 7.0.4  *sigh*

Comment: Is this issue fixed in iOS 8.1.3 ?

Comment: Generally considered to be working as of iOS 7.1. Most consistent complaint since is that it only works with store-installed apps, not development builds.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that Apple has verified and are working on fixing on the next updated

Comment: Could you please link to apple's verification of the bug?